# Magento 2 - Event - Observer - Shipping amount is correct on checkout page refresh

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5

I am trying to calculate tax on the total of subtotal+shipping-discount.
I have created an event/observer for this.

```
<event name="sales_quote_save_after">
    <observer instance="SKP\OrderGst\Observer\Checkout\SalesQuoteSaveAfter" name="skp_ordergst_observer_sales_quote_save_after"/>
</event>
```

After entering the shipping address on the checkout page first time the **getShippingAmount** returns 0, but after refreshing the page it returns the desired amount. What could be the problem?

```
    public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) {
    
    $quoteData = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $shippingAmount = $quoteData->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount(); //returns 0 first time


    $items = $quoteData->getAllItems();

    $discountAmt = 0;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $discountAmt += $item->getDiscountAmount(); //$item(get all information)
    }
    $subTotal = $quoteData->getSubtotal();
    $orderGst = (($subTotal + $shippingAmount) - $discountAmt) * 0.2;

    $gst  = round($orderGst, 2);
$quoteData->setOrderGst($gst)->save();

}
```